# Chat application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, chat

I've tried this code to make a chat application. When I run the application I am getting an `Exception: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected` and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) `no address was supplied`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace client_chatApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            textLocalIP.Text = GetLocalIp();
            textFriendsIP.Text = GetLocalIp();
        }

        //to get the local ip address
        private string GetLocalIp()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "127.0.0.1";
        }

        public void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aresult)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aresult, ref epRemote);
                if (size > 0)
                {
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];

                    receivedData = (byte[])aresult.AsyncState;
                    ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                    listMessage.Items.Add("fiend" + receivedMessage);
                }
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());

            }
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textLocalIP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
                msg = enc.GetBytes(textMessage.Text);
                sck.Send(msg);
                listMessage.Items.Add("yoy" + textMessage.Text);
                textMessage.Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
                sck.Bind(epLocal);

                epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textFriendsIP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textFriendsPort.Text));
                sck.Bind(epRemote);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                Socket dataSocket = AsyncSocket.EndAccept(_IAsyncResult);
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
                button1.Text = "connected";
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                textMessage.Focus();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: my question is how to remove the exception i am getting?

Answer (score 0):

You created the socket, but you don't bind it to a port after creation. You bind it when you want to send data.

Binding only when you want to send data is incorrect behavior.

You also only have to bind the socket to a local `IPEndpoint`. The remote `IPEndpoint` is used when you send the datagram with the function [SendTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eae4f5y0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you,could you please tell me what modification i have to do the code so to make the code working. i am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Working with sockets involves the following basic steps:

Creating socket

- Binding to the network interface
- Listen for connections or make socket connection
- Making receive and send calls

Once you are done with the first three steps, socket connection is made and you will need to use that connection to make send and receive system calls.This means, first three listed points are "do once" only and you will use it to make send and recv calls any number of times until connection is finally closed.

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/468439/Basic-Introduction-Tutorial-to-writing-sockets-in) will help you further..

Comment: thank you.please tell me what correction i have to make in my program to get the code working.